# Using rewrite to force browser refresh without further changing URL?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've just redone my site and am trying to institute some rewrites to change URLs to a new structure. I'm most of the way there, thanks to some kind support people at pair, but I know they aren't supposed to deal with such issues so I'm hoping I can get the final piece of the puzzle here.

There are four things I want to do.

1. Convert spaces to underscores.
2. Get rid of parentheses by changing things like "(2003)" to "- 2003".
3. Change the structure of html calls.
4. Force redirects so search engines get the new addresses.

Right now, this is what I have:

```
RewriteEngine On
Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(desktopscenes.com|www.desktopscenes.com)$ [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\s(.*)$ $1_$2 [N]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\((.*)$ $1-_$2
RewriteRule ^(.*)\)(.*)$ $1$2
RewriteRule ^(.*)slides/(.*)\.html$ /$1index.htm#$2.jpg [NE,R=301]
```

Everything works, except for links to jpg files, which redirect properly internally, but I can't find a way to make show the proper new address on the address bar.

For example, this old URL:

```
http://www.desktopscenes.com/Scenes from Big Sky Country (2003)/slides/First Montana Sunset.jpg
```

Properly shows the image at:

```
http://www.desktopscenes.com/Scenes_from_Big_Sky_Country_-_2003/slides/First_Montana_Sunset.jpg
```

But the browser bar doesn't show the new address, which I believe also means search engines aren't being notified of the new address.

I tried a "redirect to the same address" with "R=301" but that fails, probably because of looping. I'm not sure what else to try, any ideas?

Comment: What are your other rules? The ones that are causing the looping when you use `R=301`?

Comment: What do you mean by, "fails, probably because of looping"?

Comment: The other rule I tried was:

"RewriteRule ^(.*)slides/(.*)\.jpg$ /$1slides/$2.jpg [R=301,L]"

But it always fails when I enable it, saying the site is redirecting in a way that won't complete.

Thanks for the replies (not sure why formatting doesn't work for the reply?)

Comment: So what happens if you go to the URL `http://www.desktopscenes.com/Scenes_from_Big_Sky_Country_-_2003/index.htm#First_Montana_Sunset.jpg`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's some issues with the iterative process with the first 3 rules, try adding `[L]` flags to them.

The second problem is that your regex in the last rule (with the "slides") matches **html**, but you're giving it **jpg**.

The third problem is your `RewriteCond` is only applied to the first rule. `RewriteCond`s are only applied to the immediately following `RewriteRule`. They won't be applied globally.

So try changing your rules to look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# if the host isn't "desktopscenes.com", pass through and do nothing
Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(desktopscenes.com|www.desktopscenes.com)$ [nc]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)\s(.*)$ /$1_$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\((.*)$ /$1-_$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\)(.*)$ /$1$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)slides/(.*)\.(jpe?g|gif|png|bmp) /$1index.htm\#$2.$3 [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed reply. I actually want the html to be changed to jpg (as odd as that may sound). That is working okay. The only think that wasn't working was getting the old JPG links, after the spaces and parens were subbed out, to refresh using R=301. So what you've suggested won't work for me, but you've given me some useful ideas of what I need to change, especially the comment about RewriteCond only applying to the RewriteRule after it. Thanks again!